# Multiple CSV files to multiple tables not yet created

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

Database platform: SQL Server 2012

I have a folder with a lot of CSV's.  I require the creation of a table for each CSV.  The CSV has the column names in the first row, data in subsequent rows.

I have a handy SSIS package to iterate through a folder and import over into existing tables in a database but in this case, it is our first load and we would also like to create the tables as part of the process.

I know how to do it one at a time through the import wizard or SSIS DBO source, new table button.  I was wonder if there was a more automated way using SSIS.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or should be ongoing? What about your data types? Is there some guidance on whether we can assume the column length in the first file is representative of future sizing? What about unicode vs non-unicode data. Locale aware-ness etc, etc

Comment: Might occur 2 or 3 times.  The data types are generated in SSIS by selecting new in your destination, it does a scan of the first 100 or so rows and assumes the datatype based off the scan.  The column length of the first file should be relatively similar to subsequent files.  Unicode vs. non-unicode would be handled in SSIS and would be situational.  I think I should have been more clear that this data will be simply used as an artifact in time and will be read-only. My challenge is that it is 313 csv's.

Comment: See if you can use [this](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/data-flow-task)

Answer (score 0):

After further review of the 313 CSV's, I determined that 75% of them are lookup tables and the other 25% are relevant data.  I will simply go through each one and build out a staging table for each one and then properly build out the structure.  Only will take about 1 day to build one SSIS package to churn through all the CSV's I want to use and then I'm all set!